# python y arduino

Tags: python, arduino, raspbian

Tengo un script Python que comunica con un Arduino bajo Raspbian.
El problema que tengo es que al reiniciar Raspbian dejan de comunicar y la única solución es reprogramar el Arduino. Una vez que se reprograma, cogen comunicación y funcionan sin problema.

Dejo parte del código.

Python:

```
import serial
import time
import serial.tools.list_ports

usb_port = ''

def try_usb_communication(port,data):
try:
    ser = serial.Serial(port.device, 115200, timeout=1)
    ser.write(b'Hola, Arduino!\n') 
    received_data = ser.readline()
    data[0]=received_data
    ser.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("Fallo en la comunicacion en {} : {}",port.device,str(e))


if __name__ == "__main__":
  while(usb_port==''):
    ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
    if len(ports) == 0:
        print("No se encontraron puertos USB disponibles.")
        time.sleep(2)
    else:
        data=[None]
        for port in ports:
            if(port.device.find("USB")!=-1):
                try_usb_communication(port,data)
                if "Arduino Init" in data[0]:
                    usb_port=port.device
                    break
   ser = serial.Serial(usb_port, 115200,timeout=1)
```

Codigo en arduino:

```
void loop() {
 if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    line="";
    int size_line=0;
    while (true) {
      char readByte = Serial.read();
      if (readByte >= 32 || readByte == '\r') {
         line += readByte;
         size_line+=1;
      }
      if (readByte == '\n') { break;}
    }
 int posA=line.indexOf("Hola, Arduino!");
 if(posA>=0){
  inita=true;
  Serial.println("Arduino Init");
 }
}
```

Comment: en que funcion de arduino tienes ese codigo? entiendo que en loop, verdad? (no queda claro con el codigo que has puesto)

Comment: Si, en loop. Después hago mas cosas, pero el tema es la comunicación.